# View post runnable problems in earlier Android Versions

Tags: android, view, runnable

I open a `PopupWindow` when clicking an item of the menu. Now I tested my app on different devices and recognized, that it isn't work well in Android 2.3.3, 4.0.3, 4.0.4 (in 4.2.2 it worked fine)

```
LayoutInflater inflaterSettings = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final LinearLayout llSettings = (LinearLayout) inflaterSettings.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_menu_settings_popup, null);
...
if (popUp != null && popUp.isShowing())
    popUp.dismiss();
else if (popUp == null)
    popUp = new PopupWindow(context);
popUp.setContentView(ll);

ll.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Log.i("MainActivity#onOptionsItemSelected#run", "start run");
        popUp.showAtLocation(ll, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        width = (int) (width * 0.9);
        height = (int) (height * 0.9);
        popUp.update(width, height);
        Log.i("MainActivity#onOptionsItemSelected#run", "end run");
    }
});
Log.i("MainActivity#onOptionsItemSelected", "popup opened");
```

I wondered, because it doesn't throw any error. If I click on the menu button on device and then on the item which should open the popup, the menu (showing the items) will be closed but the popup won't be showing. If I afterwards click on the menu button for second time, the run method will be executed and the popup will be opened.

What's the reason? How to manipulate the code that it work fine in earlier Android Versions too?

Comment: I am facing the same issue..pls let me know if you found the solution

Comment: Did it not in the Runnable and it works fine for me. Just execute the code in the run method after calling `popUp.setContentView(ll)`. Hope it helps :)